# How to make my SSAS cube production ready

Tags: sql-server, ssas, data-warehouse, olap-cube

I am developing a data warehouse + a data cube for a certain client using Microsoft technologies (SSIS, SSAS and SSRS). I have almost finished doing the data warehouse. I have created a data cube in SSAS and already did the initial setting up of the cube dimensions and facts. So far it was in a development environment. We are expecting to deploy the solution at a production server in about two weeks from now.

My question is (as this is my first enterprise level cube creation), I do not know whether the cube is production ready yet. Can anyone let me know whether there are anything in specific I should do to the cube before deploying it? Also I have kept the system suggested names for the cube dimensions and measures; do I need to change them before it goes to the users?

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "enterprise level": are there specific security/audit requirements, availability levels, backup schedules or support procedures that you need to comply with?

And if your users have accepted the dimension names in the test environment and you have developed reports and even code using them, then why would you want to change them in production?

Assuming that you've already deployed cubes and packages successfully to different environments, then the things to check should be exactly the same every time: accounts and permissions, package configurations, scheduled jobs for batch processing etc.